# FirebaseMessaging: No activity found to launch app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I'm trying to receive propertly a message from FireBase when my app is in background but not working anithing. I've seen some Stackoverflow problems like mine but not working anything.
Could anyone help me to find the problem?

I need to do it when my app is in background but not working.

here AndoridManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
    tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich">


    <service
        android:name=".MyfirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
    <!--
           Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
           app to run.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />

    <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
    <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />-->

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="gizmos"
                android:scheme="example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

MyfirebaseMessagingService.java:

```
   public class MyfirebaseMessagingService extends        FirebaseMessagingService {
       public static String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

       private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotificationChannel();

    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(home);

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Intent intent = new Intent("Data");
        intent.putExtra("messageFromCloud", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

            for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
            {
                builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
            }

            onMessageReceived(builder.build());
        }
    }


}
   }
```

Comment: Well you can not use activity with `category.DEFAULT` and `category.LAUNCHER` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `MainActivity` as `Activity` of`Notification click` activity then you need to code like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="gizmos"
            android:scheme="example" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It will be automatically redirect to `MainAcitivity` on `Notification click`.

Comment: http://emergingcoders.com/ Do you guys update the number of coffee in your website, everytime when  you guys drink one?

Comment: I'm doind it on my wear os App and not working. I'm able to receive the FCM if app is in foreground but not if it's in background. Do you have anyother suggestions?

Comment: We are currently stop drinking coffee and drinking tea now! We will further add more teas and also will be add some line of codes and numbers of projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention The messaging file in manifest but this is not only the solution for open an activity through notification you need to write into intent in Messaging files.

```
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

For manifest write this code:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />



<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:permission=""
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

You need to declare it as service because notification is the part of service and run in application background when you application became closed.